# undefined method `call' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

```
 def index
    @posts = Post.published

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @posts }
      format.atom
    end
  end
```

I am taking this error.And I am new on RoR Can anybody help me.What can I do now ?

Comment: can you show the backtrace of the error?

Comment: app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:3:in `index'

Comment: is published a method or a relation?

Answer (score 8):

You have defined a scope but gave it a relation instead of a proc.  You probably have something like this:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :published, where(published: true)
end
```

Change it to this:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :published, -> { where(published: true) }
end
```

In the future, always post the entire stack trace, and the methods involved.  It's not always this easy to guess what's going on.